# Как разбить строку по значению в фрейме данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть следующая таблица:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['field_1', 'field_2'], 'B': [5, 1], 'C':['other', 'other']})
```

И я хочу разбить ее по значению в колнке `В`, чтобы получилось так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['field_1', 'field_1', 'field_1', 'field_1', 'field_1', 'field_2'], 'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'C':['other'] * 6})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какой либо встроенный метод которым можно это сделать? Или возможно это можно сделать через комбинацию таких методов?

Хотелось бы воспользоваться скоростью работы фреймворка, если это возможно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените картинку в вопросе текстом. Как исправите, напишите мне короткий комментарий, чтобы я смог отметить вопрос плюсом.

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
res = df.assign(B=df["B"].map(lambda x: [1] * x)).explode("B")
```

результат:

```
In [21]: res
Out[21]:
         A  B      C
0  field_1  1  other
0  field_1  1  other
0  field_1  1  other
0  field_1  1  other
0  field_1  1  other
1  field_2  1  other
```